# MySQL Workbench Error 1066

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1066

The following is what I'm working on for one of my query joins, I'm trying to create a table where the general screening details and combined with movie details. I keep getting the error 1066. Can anyone help or elaborate as to why?

```
SELECT  screening.ScreeningID, screening.MovieID, SeatCapacity, SeatsAvailable
    FROM screening
        LEFT JOIN movie
    ON screening.ID = movie.ScreeningID

    UNION 

SELECT MovieName, Director, Genre
    FROM movie     
        RIGHT JOIN movie
    ON screening.ID = movie.ScreeningID;
```

UPDATE:

Thanks guys for the replies, I have been an absolute complete noob and over complicated things (as usual). After some more digging around, this is what I came up with which perfectly works. I was trying to output the seating availability in a screening in one table by combining data from multiple tables.

SELECT 
    s1.ScreeningID, 
    s1.MovieID, 
    s1.SeatCapacity, 
    s1.SeatsAvailable,
    m1.Director,
    m1.MovieName,
    m1.Genre

FROM screening s1, movie m1

WHERE m1.screeningID = s1.screeningID

Comment: What was unclear about the error message? Did you read any of the other questions with the [`mysql-error-1066`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1066) tag?

Comment: Your second query has `FROM movie` but then uses `ON screening.ID`. Is there a typo in one of them?

Comment: This doesn't look like an appropriate use of `UNION`. Can you show a sample of the intended results?

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies, I have been an absolute complete noob and over complicated things (as usual). After some more digging around, this is what I came up with which perfectly works. I was trying to basically gather data from two tables and output it into one.

SELECT s1.ScreeningID, s1.MovieID, s1.SeatCapacity, s1.SeatsAvailable, m1.Director, m1.MovieName, m1.Genre

FROM screening s1, movie m1

WHERE m1.screeningID = s1.screeningID

Comment: Note: SQL error 1066 is `Not unique table/alias: 'something'` which workbench should have told you.  Please use complete error messages when available and posting for help.

Comment: @ebyrob Thank you for the tip, I did get that error, my mistake, I should have included that in my post too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias your tables and also each query that participates in the UNION must have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Note: `UNION` is two complete (mostly unrelated) `SELECT` queries.

Your second query:

```
SELECT MovieName, Director, Genre
    FROM movie     
        RIGHT JOIN movie
    ON screening.ID = movie.ScreeningID;
```

Doesn't even have a table or alias called `screening`.  (As well as column counts not matching for the `UNION`)  It also has the table `movie` included twice, so every single column you access is going to be ambiguous and generate an error unless you use table aliases e.g.: `FROM movie AS m1` etc.

I recommend starting by getting each separate query working by itself, only then combine them with a `UNION` statement.